# Drawing characters from ttf fonts with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, truetype

I am trying to make a command string for ImageMagick that should draw a character from a ttf font on a white image as large as possible for the given size and saves it as png (inspired by https://dev.to/danburzo/how-to-make-png-font-samples-with-imagemagick-part-1-29p8):

```
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:white -font path_to_font.TTF -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 'A'" -trim +repage path_to_out.png
```

but I got error messages:

convert.exe: unable to open image 'out_path.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.

convert.exe: WriteBlob Failed `out_path.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1715.

The font is not installed in the system (W10) or in IM. I tested to put the font_path and/or out_path in "..." but error remains the same.

Comment: You command has no path out_path.png. You show path_to_out.png. Have typed it different from what you use? It would seem to be objecting to your output path.

Comment: @fmw42: I used abbreviations for something like D:\....\3Strands.TTF_A_h1000_w1000.png

Comment: Check your path and be sure the image is where you think it is. Also check your spelling.